# What am i doing wrong when I switch scenes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am developing a game on sprite kit, and when the player loses they are taken to the EndScene and giving the option to play again. The problem I am having is when the player presses the button to play again they are taken to the GameScene, but instead the GameScene its appearing all blue. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I posted the EndScene below, if you need me to post the GameScene class just ask.

```
class EndScene: SKScene {
    var RestartBtn : UIButton!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        RestartBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
        RestartBtn.setTitle("Restart", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        RestartBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        RestartBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Restart"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view?.addSubview(RestartBtn)

    }

    func Restart() {
        // close EndScene and start the game again

        self.view?.presentScene(GameScene())

        RestartBtn.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

GameScene

```
import SpriteKit


struct PhysicsCatagory {
static let Enemy : UInt32 = 1 //000000000000000000000000000001
static let Bullet : UInt32 = 2 //00000000000000000000000000010
static let Player : UInt32 = 3 //00000000000000000000000000100
}


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var Score = Int()

var Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlayerGalaga.png")

var ScoreLbl = UILabel()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    Player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 5)
    Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Player.size)
    Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
    Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
    Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false



    var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self,                
    selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var EmenyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target:                                 
    self, selector: ("SpawnEnemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    self.addChild(Player)

    ScoreLbl.text = "\(Score)"
    ScoreLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
    ScoreLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, 
    alpha:0.3 )
    ScoreLbl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(ScoreLbl)


    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy) && 
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) ||
        (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) &&    
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy)){
        CollisionWithBullet(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: 
    secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy) && 
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Player) ||
        (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Player) && 
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy)){

            CollisionWithPerson(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Person: 
     secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
       }

    }


    func CollisionWithBullet(Enemy: SKSpriteNode, Bullet:SKSpriteNode){
        Enemy.removeFromParent()
        Bullet.removeFromParent()
        Score++
        ScoreLbl.text = "\(Score)"

    }
    func CollisionWithPerson(Enemy:SKSpriteNode, Person:SKSpriteNode){
    Enemy.removeFromParent()
    Player.removeFromParent()
    self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())
    ScoreLbl.removeFromSuperview()

     }



    func SpawnBullets(){
    var Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BulletGalaga.png")
    Bullet.zPosition = -5

    Bullet.position = CGPointMake(Player.position.x, Player.position.y)

    let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 0.5)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    Bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))


    Bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Bullet.size)
    Bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
    Bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
    Bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(Bullet)


}

func SpawnEnemies(){
    var Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "EnemyGalaga.png")
    var MinValue = self.size.width / 8
    var MaxValue = self.size.width - 20
    var SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    Enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)),          
    self.size.height)
    Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Enemy.size)
    Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
    Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
    Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 2.0)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    Enemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))
    self.addChild(Enemy)

     }


     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event:     
     UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        Player.position.x = location.x


        }

       }
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event:    
    UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        Player.position.x = location.x
        }

     }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
     }
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, lets have a look at the `GameScene` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, when there's a collision with person, you're removing nodes from the view, so they're still going to be gone when you recall GameScene from the restart() function in the EndScene.

What you can do is create a func initialScene() in GameScene where you create everything in that function and call it in the didMoveToView function (instead of doing it all in the didMoveToView function). That way, whenever you present the GameScene from another class, it will call that function and recreate everything you need as if you actually restarted. Hope that's a helpful start, if you need anything else just comment.

Comment: Can you help me create the initialScene() and how do I call it into didMoveToView? Sorry if it too much to ask, I am new to coding and have been learning from tutorials @AEkon

Comment: Sure, create a new function at the end of the class, and inside that put in all your code that you currently have in the didMoveToView class since that's what creates the scene. If you do addChild to nodes and things in other functions, change your code so that everything is added in the initialScene function you have just created. 

Then just put in 'initialScene()' inside your didMoveToView function, and hopefully that works as you intended

Comment: What do I do if my code has addChild to nodes? @AEkon

Comment: In the section where you are changing the scene, use .removeFromParent to remove those nodes, (or removeAllChildren to remove every child currently showing). See which works best for you.